# No usable temporary directory found with AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mlflow

I am trying to download a model with `mlflow` in an `aws lambda function` as described here: https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#referencing-artifacts

However the following error is thrown:

```
  File "/tmp/mlflow-api-server/mlflow/tracking/artifact_utils.py", line 66, in _download_artifact_from_uri
  artifact_path=artifact_path, dst_path=output_path)
  File "/tmp/mlflow-api-server/mlflow/store/artifact_repo.py", line 94, in download_artifacts
  dst_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 360, in mkdtemp
  prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 130, in _sanitize_params
  dir = gettempdir()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 298, in gettempdir
  tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 233, in _get_default_tempdir
  dirlist)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp']
```

The sklearn `model.pkl` file that `mlflow` should download has 627 Byte and the `aws lambda` limit should be 512 MB which should be enough space.

Comment: In AWS Lambda functions, you can only store files in `/tmp/`.

Comment: OK, the problem was that there was another lambda function running. Apparently, these share the /tmp/ folder and with two python virtualenv there was no disk space left. After deleting the other lambda function code was running without problems.

Comment: That sounds rather strange. Each container would only be used by one Lambda function (actually, one _version_ of one Lambda function). But, as long as it's working for you, that's great!

Comment: Indeed now it really sounds strange. With the shared tmp I was following this discussions https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=209428. Maybe someday somebody can confirm that two lambda function were blocking or find another solution...

Comment: @ReneB. only the leftovers from one or more previous, already-finished invocation of exactly the same version of exactly the same Lambds function can cause the temp space to fill up.